# Confusion with showframe when using bindingoffset and scrreprt

Tags: margins, geometry

I tried to define a bindingoffset in my onesided scrreprt document and wanted to check the layout with the showframe package, but it isn't working as expected.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Which is delivering the following results:

[image]
[image]

The offset seems to be correct, but what happened there with the frame?

Comment: Interesting, simplest workaround seems to bee loading option `showframe` for package `geometry`.

Comment: I'll drop a note to Rolf.

Comment: By the way, very very good minimal working example. Thanks and welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, there was a little bug hidden in `eso-pic`. Using the updated version that can be found on CTAN (since 2015/04/21) resolves the issue.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=5cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}[2015/04/20]
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Big thanks to Rolf Niepraschk for taking a deep look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i got it. I have to the define showframe within the geometry options instead of using the package...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```